# How can I keep track of array index in for loop?

Tags: objective-c, indexing

If I write:

```
 for (NSString* word in self.words)
{

}
```

And I want to keep track of my position in the array, how can I do that? Of course, I know I can just create an int and increment it as I loop, a.k.a. *the old-fashioned way.* I guess I'm just looking to see if there's an opportunity here to learn something. Like in python we have the handy `enumerate()` function for this sort of thing which gives you indices paired with objects.

Comment: Instead of a for loop, use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock which gives you objects and indices.

Comment: Write it in an answer with code example and then I can accept it! Unless, of course, you already have so much rep that it *doesn't even matter.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `[words indexOfObject:word];` but caution: if you have equal object in an array, it will return the first object's index. also this shows, that it is awfully inefficient — if will iterate over the array for each call.

better:

```
[words enumerateObjectsUsingBlocks:^(NSString *word,
                                     NSUInteger idx,
                                     BOOL *stop)
{
    //
}];
```

as it gives you enumeration AND the index at the same time.

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:)

Comment: I recommend that you just remove the first paragraph. There's no reason to even bring up the awful `-indexOfObject:` approach.

Comment: I think it is better to keep it, as otherwise OP might check the documentation and finds `indexOfObject:` but doesn't know of the downside, as it is not clearly stated there.